# Why does my query giving wrong fileid in mySql?

Tags: mysql

When i am trying to execute this query its giving me wrong fileid even though i am getting other information correct. 
I am not able to figure it out whats the issue with my query?
Below is my query:

```
select fileid,filename,folderpath,max(version),filetype from fileinfo
group by concat(folderpath,filename);
```

This query gives below result:

[image]

But when i am checking version of that particular file then its different below is my image:

[image]

So insted of fileid 210 it should give me 1642.

Comment: You never instructed MySQL to give you the record that contains `MAX(version)`. You just asked for `MAX(version)` and that's it.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Your selecting by one thing and grouping by another thing. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @N.B. so for that what can i do for it.

Comment: You need to instruct MySQL to also select the row containing max value. I dislike handing out copy paste solutions. If you can use the info provided to figure it out on your own, then you'll learn *why* it happens and you will be able to fix such problems on your own in the future.

Comment: Thanks @N.B. i have tried but cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using aggregate function and then `group by` does not guarantee that the selection is done from the aggregate column when you have few columns. Also in your case already pointed out that you are selecting something and the grouping with something else.

The other approach is to use left join something as below, you can add additional condition on the joining clause if you say want to make sure that the grouping also consider the `filetype` etc.

```
select 
f1.*
from fileinfo f1
left join fileinfo f2 on  concat(f1.folderpath,f1.filename) = concat(f2.folderpath,f2.filename)
and f1.version < f2.version
where f2.fileid is null;
```

**[demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1010d/1)**

Answer (score 0):

because MAX does not mean you are getting the entire row of the maxed value. Max only gets the max value of the column and it wont point in which row the value is. instead of using max use order to sort your version by desc.

Answer (score -1):

You have to group by all fields:

```
select fileid,filename,folderpath,max(version),filetype from fileinfo
```

group by fileid,concat(folderpath,filename),filetype;